# Java - Using utility method inside model class

Tags: java

Pretty new to Java so bear with me. I've got a utility method in a java class that simply gets the page title that you are on.

```
public class BasePageTitle{ 
    public Page getPageTitle(){
        page.title;    
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use this in a new class and have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

```
import com.models.pageTitle;

public String headerMeta;
public String keywords;

public class HeaderComponent{
headerMeta = "Page Title" + getPageTitle;    
keywords = "Description" + getPageTitle;
}
```

The error I seem to be getting is "method getPageTitle is undefined" but I'm 
lost because in my model class I'm importing the utility class and thought
I could reference the getPageTitle method. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `getPageTitle` is a method and as such has to be activated using brackets like this: `getPageTitle()` not like this: `getPageTitle`
2. since `getPageTitle` is not a static method - you should create an instance of `BasePageTitle` in order to call it, one of the ways to achieve this is to extend class `BasePageTitle` like MadProgrammer suggested
3. you declared `headerMeta` and `keywords` outside of class `HeaderComponent` - this code will not even compile!
4. You can't just call `headerMeta = "Page Title" + getPageTitle;` inside the class, in order to initialize a parameter you have to do it either inside a: constructor, setter, static initializer or initialization block

You'd probably want to do something like this:

```
import com.models.pageTitle;

public class HeaderComponent{
    public String headerMeta;
    public String keywords;
    private BasePageTitle bpt = new BasePageTitle();

    // this is the constructor - which is used to create instances of this class
    // and (mostly) to initialize object variables 
    public HeaderComponent(){
       headerMeta = "Page Title" + bpt.getPageTitle();    
       keywords = "Description" + bpt.getPageTitle();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for `HeaderComponent` to make use of this method, it must `extend` from `BasePageTitle`...

```
public class HeaderComponent extends BasePageTitle {...
```

This is the bases of inheritance.  See [Inheritance trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1- that method is an instance method, not a simple utility or helper method. You need to instantiate an instance of `BasePageTitle`.

2- you're calling the method incorrectly. In java method invocation requires the parentheses, even if the method takes no arguments. Also, it must be invoked on a method (if its an instance method) or a class (if static), such as `basePageObject.getPageTitle()`

Answer (score 0):

You can either extend it (inherit) as the other answer says, or you can just instantiate a class `BasePageTitle` and get the title, since it is a public non-static class.
But for that, your class `BasePageTitle` needs a field and a constructor:

```
public class BasePageTitle{
    String title;

    public BasePageTitle (String title){
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getPageTitle(){
        return this.title;    
    }
}
```

and then on your other class you do

```
public class HeaderComponent{
    //at some point you have to create the title
    BasePageTitle page = new BasePageTitle("title here");


    headerMeta = "Page Title" + page.getPageTitle();    
    keywords = "Description" + page.getPageTitle();
}
```

OBSERVATIONS:

your method `public Page getPageTitle()` doesn't do anything because there is no `return`. You have to write `return this.title;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the getPageTitle method static

```
public static Page getPageTitle()
```

and then call

```
BasePageTitle.getPageTitle();
```